# How do I add one string and part of another in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation, string-concatenation

So I'm reading a file line by line and each line has a different length kinda like:

```
['Acer', 'BUY', 'Brazilian', 'Real:' '75474574.35']
['Google', 'BUY', 'Euro:', '453453.54']
```

As you can see, each line has a different length and what I'm trying to do is add the currencies together in a single list so that it would look like:

```
['Brazilian Real', 'Euro']
```

I know that I can use ' '.join() to accomplish this, but my list looks like this whenever I use that method:

```
['Brazilian Real:', 'Euro:']
```

I can get very close, except there are colons at the end of my list. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: `str.strip(':')` strips all `:` characters from the beginning and end of a string

Comment: Right now, I'm using a nested while loop to go through each line and append the currency name to a new list. How can I implement strip() to get rid of all of the colons from every element in my newly appended list?

Comment: what does your append line look like? i would suggest calling string before appending. also, you can use a for loop to iterate through your lines with `for line in infile`, that would probably be easier than a while looop

Comment: My append looks like  `currency_name.append(' '.join(line[2:x]))` where x is `len(line) - 1`.

Comment: `currency_name.append(' '.join(line[2:x]).strip(':'))` will then give you what you want (i am assuming `line` is the first list as above) this calls `strip` on the return value of `' '.join()` (which is the string end up appending)

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.